# PHP: Installing mbstring - package unavailable

Tags: php, apache-http-server

I want to install mbstring in PHP. I used these commands in ssh:

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

I tried all the below repository, but I always get:

> No package php-mbstring available.

```
sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
baseurl=http://centos.intergenia.de/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
baseurl=http://dev.centos.org/centos/$releasever/testing/$basearch/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to install PHP mbstring on CentOS 6.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2)

Comment: hey cbuckley,, in that question it provides baseurl=http://centos.intergenia.de/$releasever/updates/$basearch/ but it dont work for me

Answer (score 1):

Open up a terminal (`#` - 'shorthand' for terminal) and run these commands:

```
# cd ~
# wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.3/os/i386/Packages/php-mbstring-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.i686.rpm
# rpm –ivh php-mbstring-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.i686.rpm
```

or use `ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.3/os/x86_64/Packages/php-mbstring-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64.rpm` for 64-bit, depending on your system.

If you use a desktop interface (most likely), you can just double click on the .rpm file in the file browser to install, instead of using terminal.
This is kind of the 'old' way to install things. Before `yum` simplified things.

Please note that you need to run as `root`. The best way to do so is to type `sudo` before each command. Example:

```
sudo rpm –ivh php-mbstring-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.i686.rpm
```

Comment: where sould i use # wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.3/os/i386/Packages/php-mbstring-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.i686.rpm